# Assigning one array to another array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I am beginner in c++ , can someone explain to me this

```
char a[]="Hello";

char b[]=a; // is not legal
```

whereas,

```
char a[]="Hello";

char* b=a; // is legal
```

If a array cannot be copied or assigned to another array , why is it so that it is possible to be passed as a parameter , where a copy of the value passed is always made in the method

```
void copy(char[] a){....}

char[] a="Hello";

copy(a);
```

Comment: It is `pass by reference`

Comment: The weird rules about arrays are inherited from 1970's C programming and nobody has ever changed them because too much existing code would break. Instead, you are discourage from using arrays in C++; instead use `std::vector` which has the behaviour that arrays do in most high-level languages.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c?rq=1) is quite long, but it's well worth the read. All your questions are answered in it.

Comment: @AhmedHamdy, That's not pass by reference. The array decays to a pointer, which is **copied** into the function's parameter, which itself is equivalent to having a parameter `char *a`. Calling this pass by reference conflicts with actually passing by reference, via the parameter *being* a reference (i.e. it has the `&`).

Answer (score 18):

It isn't copying the array; it's turning it to a pointer. If you modify it, you'll see for yourself:

```
void f(int x[]) { x[0]=7; }
...
int tst[] = {1,2,3};
f(tst); // tst[0] now equals 7
```

If you need to copy an array, use [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/):

```
int a1[] = {1,2,3};
int a2[3];
std::copy(std::begin(a1), std::end(a1), std::begin(a2));
```

If you find yourself doing that, you might want to use an [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

Comment: What is the difference between an `std::array` and the arrays used in the example?

Answer (score 8):

The array is silently (implicitly) converted to a pointer in the function declaration, and the pointer is copied. Of course the copied pointer points to the same location as the original, so you can modify the data in the original array via the copied pointer in your function.